# Excel Formula - returning data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that has four columns of data.

I want column number *four* (`D`) to display the value of column *three* (`C`) **IF** the number next to it in column *two* (`B`) matches **ANY** number in column *one* (`A`), and blank otherwise.

Example below:

```
 one     two     three   four
 45      45      80      80
 52      65      60
 525     25      20      20
 25      565     40
 25      52      60      60
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You've done a good job of explaining your your question. Only thing you forgot to tell us is what you have tried in order to resolve this on your own. For the sake of improving your post, even though you received an answer, you really should [edit] your question to include those details for others who may read this question and attempt to answer it. Remember to ask a specific question like; *"How can I return the value of one cell if other cells match a criteria?"*

Comment: It might be good to clarify the rules a bit because a few cases are ambiguous.  Are you talking about an exact match of the entire number vs. a partial match vs. match of the individual digits regardless of order?  For example, the "20" result could be because there is an exact match with 25 or because 525 contains 25.  The 60 match could be because there is an exact match with 52, or because 52 is contained in 525, or because 25 contains the digits 5 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table starts in cell A1, I think this formula should do it:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH($B1;$A$1:$A$5;0)>0;"")="";"";$C1)
```

The `MATCH`-statement searches for the value in B1 in the A1:A5 range, and returns a #N/A-error if it can't find the value (the third argument, 0, means we want an exact match).

Then the `IFERROR`-statement returns an empty string, if the statement inside it returns an error, otherwise it returns the position of the value found.

The `IF`-statement checks if `IFERROR` returns an empty string, if true it prints an empty string to the cell, otherwise it prints the value in C1.

Depending a bit on your regional settings, you may have to change the semicolons in the formula to commas to get it to work.

Comment: I think it could be a bit neater      `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($B1,$A$1:$A$5,0)),"",$C1)`